# hive can't create a table

Tags: hadoop, hive

First is wrong,but the second is OK.They are almost the same.Their different is **lines terminated by '\n'**  's position.I don't know why.Please help me.

[image]

Comment: there is no second screenshot, add it,

Comment: they are all contained in this screenshot.

Comment: @RuiLuo Next time please include the actual text, rather than a screenshot of it. This way people can't copy fragments, and those who would quickly try to reproduce the situation. (In this case, you would probably want to format it using the <> button)

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin OK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Order is

```
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\001'
COLLECTION ITEMS TERMINATED BY '\002'
MAP KEYS TERMINATED BY '\003'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
```

The ROW FORMAT DELIMITED sequence of keywords must appear before any of the other
clauses, with the exception of the STORED AS … clause.

The character \001 is the octal code for ^A. The clause ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS
TERMINATED BY '\001' means that Hive will use the ^A character to separate fields.

Similarly, the character \002 is the octal code for ^B. The clause ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
COLLECTION ITEMS TERMINATED BY '\002' means that Hive will use the ^B character to
separate collection items.

Finally, the character \003 is the octal code for ^C. The clause ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
MAP KEYS TERMINATED BY '\003' means that Hive will use the ^C character to separate
map keys from values.

The clause LINES TERMINATED BY '…' and STORED AS … do not require the ROW FORMAT
DELIMITED keywords.
Actually, it turns out that Hive does not currently support any character for **LINES
TERMINATED BY** … other than '\n'. So this clause has limited utility today.

Reference from the Programming Hive book PageNo:47

Comment: I want to konw why " LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'  "  must put in the end?

Comment: @RuiLuo The question of why it must be put there, is answered by 'that is how it is implemented' (If I understand correctly). If you would want to know why it is implemented in that way, I don't think that kind of question would be on topic for this site. (As questions of why typically can't be answered properly with more than guesswork).